# `SELECT FOR UPDATE` in master-master mysql setup

Tags: mysql, replication

I am benchmarking a database schema with a dozen workers processes and was wondering what a SELECT FOR UPDATE does in a master-master configuration.

For the moment it seems to work, but I am either doing INSERT on one and SELECT FOR UPDATE + UPDATE on the other, or doing it on both at the same time.

There is a big lag in the replication (the numbers shows that it keeps growing over time). What would happen if I do some SELECT FOR UPDATE + UPDATE on both while still doing some INSERT on one and not both ?

Can the database be corrupted ?

Comment: Are you writing to the same tables on both masters?

Comment: Yes, same table, same schema.

Comment: You don't want to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Generally, it is considered a very bad idea to write to both masters in master/master replication, unless you are writing to different schemas.**

MySQL replication is asynchronous (MySQL 5.5 has "semi-synchronous" replication, but it's still asynchronous in practice).  There is no mechanism to synchronize locks or detect conflicts between hosts.

Consider what happens in this situation

```
master1> BEGIN;
master1> SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 7 FOR UPDATE;
master1> UPDATE talbe SET col = "Newton" WHERE id = 7;

master2> BEGIN;
master2> SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 7 FOR UPDATE;
master2> UPDATE table SET col = "Aaron" WHERE id = 7;

master1> COMMIT;
master2> COMMIT;
```

Depending on timing, replication lag, and whether you have ROW or STATEMENT based replication, you might end up with different data on different hosts.  Certainly, master1's FOR UPDATE will not lock the rows on master2 and vice versa, thus negating the utility of FOR UPDATE (which is [to be avoided](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/5-subtle-ways-youre-using-mysql-as-a-queue-and-why-itll-bite-you/)).

In your situation you could, at best, end up with broken replication and at worst end up with silent data sync issues between the servers.

Comment: Your answer would look a lot messier if we are talking Schooner or XtraDB Cluster. +1 !!!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Schooner, but I think Percona XtraDB Cluster (which is Galera compiled into Percona Server) would handle this situation better because of synchronous replication and the in-memory certification process that occurs.  In my example, one of those COMMITs would just outright fail instead of causing data sync issues.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, but are you saing that table locking cannot be used with replication?